# Python replace a character with anther column in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I try to replace a specific character ',2' in a column with another column's string

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'event':['Sunday,2eat','MondayDonteat','FridayDont,2'],'day':[2021,2022,2023]})
```

my approach does't work

```
df['event'].str.replace(',2', df['day'].str)
```

expected output

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'event':['Sunday2021eat','MondayDonteat','FridayDont2023'],'day':[2021,2022,2023]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["event"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: x["event"].replace(",2", str(x["day"])), axis=1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
            event   day
0   Sunday2021eat  2021
1   MondayDonteat  2022
2  FridayDont2023  2023
```

Comment: The only annoying thing about `apply` is that it's not parallelized, so this operation may be inefficient on much larger datasets. For this question, though, it works quite well.